# Unsupported metadata version when using Hilt 2.40.1 with Kotlin 1.9.10

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-hilt

I am getting this error:

```
> Task :app:hiltJavaCompileDebug
error: [Hilt]
  Unsupported metadata version. Check that your Kotlin version is >= 1.0: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unsupported metadata version. Check that your Kotlin version is >= 1.0
    at dagger.internal.codegen.kotlin.KotlinMetadata.metadataOf(KotlinMetadata.java:206)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.kotlin.KotlinMetadata.from(KotlinMetadata.java:187)
```

- Dagger Hilt 2.40.1
- Kotlin 1.9.10
- Gradle 8.2.0

Here is my code

Top-level `gradle`

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        kotlin_version = '1.9.10'
        compose_version = '1.5.3'
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        def gradle = '8.2.0'
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:$gradle"

        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        def hilt = '2.40.1'
        classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:$hilt"

        def detekt='1.18.1'
        classpath "io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt:detekt-gradle-plugin:$detekt"

    }
}

tasks.register('clean', Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

App-level `gradle`

```
    plugins {
        id 'com.android.application'
        id 'kotlin-android'
        id 'kotlin-kapt'
        id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
        id 'kotlin-parcelize'
        id 'io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt'
    }

    android {
        compileSdk 34

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.gagan.newsapp"
            minSdk 23
            targetSdk 34
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"

            testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
            vectorDrawables {
                useSupportLibrary true
            }
        }

        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        }
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = '11'
        }
        buildFeatures {
            compose true
        }
        composeOptions {
            kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion "1.5.3"
            kotlinCompilerVersion "1.9.10"
        }
        packagingOptions {
            resources {
                excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
            }
        }
        namespace 'com.gagan.newsapp'
    }

    kapt {
        correctErrorTypes = true
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0'
        implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
        implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.10.0'
        implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:1.5.4"
        implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:1.5.4"
        implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:1.5.4"
        implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.2' // Test
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
        androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:1.5.4"
        debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:1.5.4"
        androidTestImplementation('androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.5.1') {
            exclude module: "protobuf-lite"
        }

        implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout-compose:1.0.1"

        implementation "androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.8.1"

        def retrofit = "2.9.0"
        implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofit"
        implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:$retrofit"

        def moshi = "1.12.0"
        implementation "com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin:$moshi"
        implementation "com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin-codegen:$moshi"

        def hilt = "2.40.1"
        implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$hilt"
        implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:$hilt"

        implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.1.0"

        implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.7.5"

        def hilt_lifecycle_view_model = "1.0.0-alpha03"
        implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:$hilt_lifecycle_view_model"
        implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.1.0"

        def coroutines = "1.6.4"
        implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$coroutines"
        testImplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-test:$coroutines"
        implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.7.1"

        implementation "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:1.5.4"

        implementation "io.coil-kt:coil-compose:1.4.0"

        def navigation_animation = "0.16.1"
        implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-navigation-animation:$navigation_animation"

        implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.6.1"
    //    ksp "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.6.1"
        implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:2.6.1"
        implementation "androidx.room:room-rxjava2:2.6.1"
        implementation "androidx.room:room-guava:2.6.1"
        testImplementation("androidx.room:room-testing:2.6.1")
        androidTestImplementation("androidx.room:room-testing:2.6.1")

        testImplementation("androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.2.0")
        androidTestImplementation("androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.2.0")

        testImplementation("org.mockito:mockito-core:4.0.0")
        testImplementation("com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2:mockito-kotlin:2.2.0")


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing version **compatibility** of `Hilt` And `Kotlin`. Either you can decrease Kotlin version to `1.6.x` Or Increase the Hilt Version to `2.48`

Here is the change you need for Kotlin Version `1.9.10`

Put this in **build.gradle(project)**

```
plugins{
     id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android") version "2.48" apply false
}
```

And add this in build.gradle(app-level)

```
plugins{
    id ("kotlin-kapt")
    id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android")
}

dependencies{
     implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.48")
     kapt("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.48")
}
```

Comment: I am starting to get a new error as soon as I changed the hilt version to 2.48   

Unable to load class 'com.google.devtools.ksp.gradle.KspTaskJvm'
com.google.devtools.ksp.gradle.KspTaskJvm

Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)

Comment: Error shows that you need to change your ksp version compatible with the kotlin version

Comment: how to know which Kotlin version matches to android-hilt version? guide me, please.